# I want the rotation of a wheel given the rotation of a cycloid as measured by a gyroscope

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCZjoCJZ89A

I have a mems gyroscope on a bicycle wheel
At constant velocity the angularAcceleration of the wheel varies because the sensor is following the path of a cycloid. I would like to find other angular acceleration of the wheel.
From the parametric equation.
$$D_x=f(\text{wheel Rotation})$$
$$D_y=g(\text{wheelRotation})$$
$$D_x=rcos(\text{gyroscope Reading})=f(\text{wheelRotation})$$
$$D_y=rsin(\text{gyroscope Reading})=g(\text{wheelRotation})$$
Solve for $$wheelRotation$$ in maple then differentiate numerially. Does it sound like a plan or should i go back to washin dishes

Yes the wheel is going down rhe road at almost constant velocity. The sensor,an angular rate sensor,is tracing out the path of a cycloid. this causes false reading because the radius of curvature changes  and as the circle is streched out so to speak. What i want calculate is the actual angular velocity of the wheel

Comment: I find this post very hard to understand. Could you use correct grammar and spelling?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you have an accelerometer on the wheel of a bicycle which is moving down the road at a constant speed?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a diagram to your question. Makes it a bit easier to understand, I think. I also tried formatting your equations but they were pretty clumsy to begin with so you might want to go back and clear things up. It's not very clear.

Comment: Is that solvable? From the diagram it looks like there are three unknowns: x, y, and \$$\theta \$$ but only two equations.

Comment: I have a mems gyroscope or angular rate sensor. The wheel is rolling down the road. Yes the speed can be constant. The sensor traces the path of a cycloid . This cause angular velocity of near double the speed at the top and near 0 at the bottom. What I want to calculate is the acutual rotation of the of the wheel without the translation

Comment: Dx and dy can be calculated from the gyroscope

Comment: Oh, you're planning on integrating out the x and y? That sounds like a doozy on top of the integration errors. I would almost try to find a way to grab the peak and minimum angular velocity and find the wheel angular velocity that fits that than try to figure out the x and y. The best position would obviously be mounting at the center. The second best position would be right at the edge because the minimum angular velocity would directly correspond to the wheel at pure rotation but that's not physically practical. I would have just used a magnetic encoder to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

If the angular velocity is constant, then it is just 2π radians divided by the time to go from x = 0 to x = 2πa. In that case, the only other acceleration would be the centripetal acceleration of some point on the wheel. For your sensor, that would be its maximum vertical acceleration, and you can calculate the angular velocity from that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

with:
$$x=a \left( \theta-\sin \left( \theta \right)  \right) \\
y=a \left( 1-\cos \left( \theta \right)  \right) $$

you obtain the path length $~s$

$$s=\int\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,d\theta\\
s=2\,{\frac {\sin \left( \theta \right) {\it arctanh} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt 
{2}\sqrt {1+\cos \left( \theta \right) } \right) }{\sqrt {1+\cos
 \left( \theta \right) }\sqrt {1-\cos \left( \theta \right) }}}
$$

substitute $~cos(\theta)=u~,\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{1-u^2}~$ and solve u, you obtain
$$u=-1+2\, \left( \tanh \left( \frac 12\,\sqrt {{s^2}} \right)  \right) ^{2}\quad \Rightarrow\\
\theta=\arccos(u(s))$$

from here you obtain the angular velocity

$$\dot\theta=\pm{\frac {\sinh \left( s \right) \sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {\cosh \left( s
 \right) -1} \left( \cosh \left( s \right) +1 \right) }}\,\underbrace{\frac{ds}{dt}}_{v}
$$

Comment: Thanks Eli. Could you solve the slightly different equation of a curtate cycloid because the sensor is not at the edge of the bike and the parametric equations  are a bit different.

Comment: For a curtate cycloid you don't have analytical solation because you can't obtain $~\theta=\theta(s)~$ instead you have to solve this differential equation 
$~{\frac {d}{dt}}\theta \left( t \right) ={\frac {-i \left( -a+b\cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \right) v}{\sqrt {-{a}^{2}+2
\,ab\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) -{b}^{2}}}}
$

Comment: Ok. Thanks again Eli.